# Connecting to sql database

Tags: codenameone

(I am a sql noob and I just can not figure this out on my own)

For some time now I have been trying to establish a connection to a SQL database in codename one but to no avail. First I tried connecting to a MariaDB database from one.com. All that's needed for the connection is

```
Database db = Display.getInstance().openOrCreate("databaseName");
```

if I am not mistaken, but I am guessing this implies that I have somehow already established a connection to the database. This is not the case however so it creates a new .sql file, right? I can recall that you can connect to a database in the services tab in Netbeans. I chose the MySQL(Connector/ J Driver) which should work with MariaDB, or should it? I entered all my data and i says that it can not establish connection to the database.

[the error i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnb3d.png)

So I thought I might as well try using localhost. I used XAMPP to host a database and connected in the netbeans services tab.

[connected?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqpXm.png)

Now testing was needed to see if this works. I started the SQL journey with this https://www.codenameone.com/manual/files-storage-networking.html#_sql and integrated the part after "You can probably integrate this code into your app as a debugging tool". I changed database name to "mybase" (it's existance can be confirmed in picture 2). Ran the app, opened the dialog, entered "select ID from customers" and got: java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: customers) It does not get past the first call to "executeQuery". The customers table definitely exists so what am I missing to establish connection?

I really need instructions to connect to the localhost database and ideally also to the one hosted by my webhost provider.

Thanks,
Jona

Answer (score 2):

The Database class is to access the SQLite DB on the mobile device. To connect to external databases, you'd have to do something different, such as a ConnectionRequest or Socket I think.

Comment: Care to elaborate @James H ?

Comment: See [this](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/connecting-to-a-mysql-database.html) & [this](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/connecting-to-a-mysql-database-part-2.html) on connecting to a remote DB. As James pointed out Database connects to the SQLite database that's builtin to the device, you can't connect directly to remote databases as the network connection is flaky and it's a HUGE security problem to do something like that. The articles above show a way to implement this